# Translation of tricky ER Diagram

Tags: sql, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm doing a project for my Database exam, and I'm stuck at a tricky point. This is an excerpt of my ER diagram:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1WQd.png]

As you can see, the entity Employee is generalization of Waiter and Cook. Head waiter and Chief cook are specializations of respectively Waiter and Cook. Only chiefs can fullfill an Order (non included in this excerpt) to the supplier. Obiously only one Chief at a time can Fulfil an order (I've made a single Fulfilment relationship to make the diagram less messy).

After remodeling the ER diagram (sorry if I'm not using the correct words, I'm translating in English), this is the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOyD.png]

So an Employee must have a Role (Waiter, Cook or whatever else), and for each role there could (obviously) be only one Chief. I really don't know if this is correct, the double generalization confuses me a lot.

Next step is the logical diagram (tables), and this is a total mess!
This is a possible solution:

[image]

This is a possible translation to the relational model (with an Unique Not Null constraint on FK2 in tblChief) , but it has a weakness: if you change Employees role in tblEmployee, tblChief won't see this error and integrity will be broken. Could adding a FK between tblEmployee(Role) and tblChief(Role) be a good solution? Or would it be ugly/messy?

I've thought of a second possible solution. I prefer it, but still I don't know if it's OK:

[image]

Here I've merged the entity Role with the entity Chief in a single table. The field Chief references IDEmployee, again it must be Unique and Not Null.

Are these solutions correct? I'm sure that this will be a big mess when inserting and updating Employees and Roles (AFAIK it can't be done without temporarily removing the integrity checks). Could be this done in a different way?

Sorry for the long post (and for the image links, but I can't post them directly) and many thanks if you'll answer me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last diagram does not make sense.

Each employee has 1 role (this is a FK relationship)

Each role **can have** one superior role.  This is a nullable FK relationship back to the role table.  (Itself).  Not to employee as you have it.

To find all employees that are managers you would have a select statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
WHERE roleID in (SELECT roleID 
                 FROM role 
                 WHERE superiorID IS NULL)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees E
LEFT JOIN role R ON E.roleID = R.roleID
WHERE R.superiorID IS NULL
```

Comment: It makes sense, but probably I didn't explained well the diagram: each role has one superior role (in the set of waiters I will have a  Head waiter etc.), but i must assign this role to an Employee. I won't insert in tblRole this:
1 "Waiter" NULL
2 "Head Waiter" 1

But this:
1 "Waiter" 123
2 "Cook" 401

Where 123 and 401 are the Employees that are Head waiter and Chief cook. I hope that now I've explained well

Comment: The role table should not contain information about about employees.  But this is my opinion.  Let me know how you do on the exam.

Comment: OK I've understood what you mean :) Took me a while! You mean a recursive relationship in Role, don't you? But this introduces a new problem: only chiefs should make orders, with this design I can't guarantee it. Somehow I should have another table to keep track who's Chief of a particular Role, so only Chiefs can make orders

Comment: Is it only one level deep?  Then you have it right there with the superiorID field.

Comment: Yes, just one level. What does it mean "Then you have it right there"?

Comment: One of the fields in the role table is the superiorID field -- it is a FK that points to the role table.  Thus every role points to the superior role for that role.  Then you can join to the employee table if you want to see who the employee is that has that role.  It is right there.

Comment: OK, now it's clear thanks! But this case supposes some more logic to make an order, I mean: an Employee wants to make an order. I make a check if he's a superior. If the answer is true, he's allowed to fulfil an order, otherwise not. This isn't done at a schema level, but with e.g. stored procedure. Am I right?

Comment: Of course, this is a logic / business rule -- much better to do it in the application tier.

Comment: Because imagine what happens when it changes, they add sou-cheifs -- you don't want to have to change the db layer constraints in order to implement that change.